# Visual studio emulator for android does not support

Tags: android, emulation, nativescript

i have windows 7 64bit trying to getting started with NativeScript.
and getting the error when trying to install the Android studio emulator
[Emulator for Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R31Ff.png)

i tried to get an older version emulator to get this work but dint find
any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Android Studio and use the emulator from there .

You can download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/)